# Changing DROP TABLE code to APPEND/INSERT

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

This code currently is using a DROP TABLE to transfer data from Access to SQL Server, that is when it was intended for one person to use. Now it is going to be used by multiple people so I need to alter the code to APPEND. I am trying to figure out how to get it to check the destination table to see if the record already exists, if it does it will skip over it, if not it will write that employees data to the table. The SQL table is prebuilt and it has a ROW ID column and TIME STAMP column that the access table does not have in order to keep track of the records being entered.

The code currently looks like:

```
Public Function Update()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim err As DAO.Error
Const DestinationTableName = "AC_CDData"
Const ConnectionString = _
    "ODBC;" & _
        "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
        "Server=SERVER;" & _
        "Database=DB;" & _
        "UID=ID;" & _
        "PWD=PW;"
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.Connect = ConnectionString
qdf.SQL = _
    "IF EXISTS " & _
        "(" & _
            "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES " & _
            "WHERE TABLE_NAME='" & DestinationTableName & " '" & _
        ") " & _
    "DROP TABLE [" & DestinationTableName & "]"
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
On Error GoTo Update_qdfError
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
On Error GoTo 0
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
    acExport, _
    "ODBC Database", _
    ConnectionString, _
    acTable, _
    "CDData", _
    DestinationTableName, _
    False
Exit Function

Update_qdfError:
For Each err In DAO.Errors
MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & err.Number
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setup a simple standared linked table to SQL server in Access.

Since the column of the existing record is a primary key (or simply an index set = unique), then you only need ONE LINE of code to append your data.

This will work:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO AC_CDData SELECT * FROM CDData;"
```

Any row that already exists will be ignored due to key (or index) violation. Thus only new non existing records will be appended with the above one line of code.

Edit:
As for the target table being a SQL linked table? Your application on startup does not care if you have some linked tables. Your application does not use nor care about such linked tables unless you use them.

The assuming here is you have a local data table. The linked table ONLY comes into play when you going to do the export. As noted you cannot export unless you are connected to SQL server. The “code” or testing if you are connected is not dealt with in this question but even if it was part of the question in both cases you still have to test for a connection and once again when you do finally determine you have a connect and you decide to export then again the linked table as per above will work.

So there is really no reason I can think of as to why having a linked table that is ONLY used during the append to the SQL table will be any kind of issue or problem.

As stated, then the one line of VBA code should suffice here.

Comment: That is what I would have done, but there will not always be a connection to the sql server. So there is a local table in the ACCESS DB that the data is saved to. I need this code to also upload that data when it runs as well to the sql server table.

Comment: It not clear what you mean by “not always a connected”. If you going to do the export then you MUST have a valid connection to sql server else how can you export? The fact of a linked table does not matter until you actually use it. So on application startup there is no care or worry as to you are actually connected or not. And this thus means the “existence” of a linked table means nothing until you actually use it.

Comment: I have amended the response to explain the linked table issue.

Comment: I tried that I keep getting the error: RUN TIME ERROR 3024: COULD NOT FIND FILE c:\Users......

Comment: The purpose of this code is to write the data to sql server ONLY if there is a connection, if not it is simply supposed to just keep the data stored on the local table until the next time the db is opened and a connection is established

Comment: Right but where in your question do you ask to check if there is a connection? (you do not) And where in your code posted do you check for a valid connection? (it does not). If this is part of this question and is important then amend your question to reflect this desire. However in ALL cases you cannot transfer data unless you FIRST TEST and CHECK if a valid SQL connection exits. Once you do this check then my example code or your posted code can be run. The test for a connection needs to OCCUR BEFORE attempt to run my or your code.

Comment: You state the code gives some error Code posted runs fine. AC_DATA is a linked table to SQL server and CCData is a local table. As noted in ALL CASES and in ALL examples it is assumed we have a valid connection AT TIME of the data transfer attempt. Since in a typical application there could but 100’s of places in which one transfers data then the test of a valid connection should be a separate routine and in fact likely a separate question. So testing for a valid connection is a separate question and as noted if it not a separate question you left out this MASSIVE issue in your question.

Comment: Having linked table does not force a connection when you launch the application. You are free open + use application and edit ONLY local tables. You can then close the application. ONLY WHEN you attempt to do a transfer will the linked table be used. The fact of having a linked table does not create or force some connection UNTIL YOU ACTUALLY USE THE LINKED TABLE. You thus  have to amend your question to explain to everyone here HOW/WHEN/WHERE you plan to do this transfer but again that issue is separate and regardless of having the existence of a linked table.

Answer (score 2):

The `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` does a complete transfer of the data from the Access table, to the SQL Server database. This function can not do partial inserts based on existing records.

What you can do, however, is export the data into a temporary new table (without dropping the existing table), followed by executing an SQL `MERGE` statement, to incorporate the new records of the temporary table, with the existing table.

You'll need to know how to perform SQL queries from VBA against your SQL database, and you'll need to know how to use the SQL `MERGE` statement. A google search will quickly give you the answer to both.

Answer (score 0):

In case of concurrent usage the process need to be changed:

1. `DestinationTableName` must be unique per session (thread) and need to be changed (from constant to variable)
2. Tabel with `DestinationTableName` neame need and need to be dropped before the export data (as it was in current solution).
3. `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` will not change - the data will be exported into the unique temp table.
4. For simplifying the `Merge` process the stored procedure can be written on the SQL Server side (with all needed to APSERT logic) with the source table name as parameter. This SP need to be called after the `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` completion

In this case the flow will be the following:

- `DestinationTableName` unique name generation
- Dropping this table on the SQL Server side (`qdf.Execute ...`)
- Export data to the temp table (`DoCmd.TransferDatabase ...`)
- Merge data in the SQL Server side (call to created SP with needed logic of update / insert)